# Calling python dictionary of function from class

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm relatively new to python and would like to make a class that has a dictionary that corresponds to different methods in the class. I currently have :

```
class Test:
  functions = {"Test1":test1, "Test2":test2}

  def test1(self, arg1):
    print "test1"

  def test2(self, arg1):
    print "test2" + arg1

  def call_me(self, arg):
    self.functions[arg](arg)
```

Then in my main.py I have the following:

```
from Test import Test

t = Test()

t.call_me('Test1')
```

When I call this function I get an error saying name test1 is not defined. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got multiple problems here.

First, in this line:

```
functions = {"Test1":test1, "Test2":test2}
```

At the time Python executes this line of code, there is nothing called `test1` or `test2`, so you're going to get an immediate `NameError`. If you want to do things this way, you're going to have define `functions` *after* all of the functions have been defined, not before.

---

Next, on the same line, `test1` and `test2` at this point are plain-old functions. But you're trying to call them as if they were *methods*, with the magic `self` and everything. That isn't going to work. If you understand how methods work, it should be obvious that you can work around this in the `call_me` method:

```
def call_me(self, arg): self.functions[arg].__get__(self, type(self))(arg)
```

(In this case, you can also get away with just explicitly passing `self` as an extra argument. But make sure you understand why before doing that.)

---

Finally, you're trying to call `call_me` with the function `test1`, instead of the name `'Test1'`. Presumably the whole reason you've created this mapping is so that you can use the names (dynamically, as strings), so let's actually use them:

```
t.call_me('Test1')
```

---

Note that if the only reason you can't use `getattr` is that the runtime names you want to look up aren't the same as the method names you want to define, you can always have a map of strings to strings, and look up the resulting strings with `getattr`, which avoids all the other problems here. Borrowing from [aruisdante's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26663091/908494), adding in the name lookup and remembering to pass `arg`:

```
functions = {"Test1": "test1", "Test2": "test2"}

def call_me(self, arg):
    return getattr(self, self.functions[arg])(arg)
```

Comment: Upvote for you because of the suggestion of a static str:str map to solve the arbitrary mapping issue while still using `getattr` to solve the binding issue.

Comment: @aruisdante: And no downvote for spelling your name wrong in the link? :) I'll go fix that…

Answer (score 7):

You need string quotes around your argument, and the T needs to be capitalized:

```
t.call_me('Test1')
```

However, python already has the functionality you're trying to replicate built into it via the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) method. I.E. you can just do:

```
def call_me(self, arg):
    return getattr(self, arg)()
```

Note that in this case, the name must be exactly the same as the method name or it will raise an `AttributeError`, so it would be:

```
t.call_me('test1')
```

**UPDATE**

So now that you've edited your question, it's clear what the problem is:

```
class Test:
    functions = {"Test1":test1, "Test2":test2}
```

This is defining `functions` at the static/class scope. At this point, `test1` and `test2` haven't actually been created yet, and they aren't bound to a class instance (so no way to know what `self` should be). The 'correct' solution if you wanted to have arbitrary mappings (so `getattr` doesn't fit the bill) would be to move this inside an `__init__()`:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._functions = {"Test1":self.test1, "Test2":self.test2}

    def call_me(self, arg):
        return self._functions[arg](arg)
```

Comment: I don't think getattr is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to avoid a lot of if else statements. I'm reading in a file and each keyword found in the file will trigger a different function call. Thus I need a way to associate a key (the keyword found in the file) with a value (it's corresponding function).

Comment: I mean, assuming the names are exact, `getattr` will do what you want. See my updated answer... I think a lot of us actually misread what you did and missed why it didn't work.

Comment: @aruisdante: No, that's not the only problem he had. He's also defining a dict with values that don't exist yet, and using functions as if they were methods; just solving the first problem won't help at all with the other two, they still also need to be solved.

Comment: @abarnert is right, that was my issues, thanks! Will give best answer once the time out is done.

Comment: @abarnert yep, that's what I was in the middle of editing into my answer ;) Most of us seemed to have missed that because we immediately saw the missing string quotes and no caps and locked onto that.

Answer (score 0):

In your dict, `"Test1"` and `"Test2"` are capitalized, while the corresponding functions are not. Change the dict keys to lowercase and everything should work.