# Python test http-server: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a test http-server for a personal IoT project I"ve got going. My project has its own web-server that responds to certain 'page load' requests. Now I'm trying to expand the web-page itself. Now I could develop the actual server itself simultaneously but downloading it to the IoT device every iteration is extraordinarily slow so I've decided to write a test-server on my machine instead.

The test-server is written in python. The code below is the test-server in its entirety:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import string

PORT = 8000

class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        self.pageFuncs = { "/Lights": self.doLightsPage,
                           "/Show": self.doShowPage,
                           "/Static": self.doShowTypePage,
                           "/Effects": self.doShowTypePage,
                           "/Playlist": self.doShowTypePage,
                           "/Select": self.doControlTypePage,
                           "/Controls": self.doControlTypePage,
                           "/query": self.doQueryResultsPage }

        self.STATIC_SHOW_TYPE = 0
        self.EFFECTS_SHOW_TYPE = 1
        self.PLAYLIST_SHOW_TYPE = 2

        self.SELECT_CTRL_TYPE = 0
        self.CONTROL_CTRL_TYPE = 1

        self.LightsOn = 0
        self.LightShowOn = 0

        self.showType = STATIC_SHOW_TYPE
        self.ctrlType = SELECT_CTRL_TYPE

    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            page_name = self.path
            if (page_name in pageFuncs):
                print (page_name)
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header("Content-type", "text/json")
                self.end_headers()
                self.pageFuncs[page_name](self)
                return
            else:
                super().do_GET()

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

        except :
            pass

    def doLightsPage(self):
        self.bLightsOn ^= 1
        return doQueryResultsPage()

    def doShowPage(self):
        self.bLightShowOn ^= 1
        return doQueryResultsPage()

    def doShowTypePage(self):
        if (self.path == '/Static') :
            self.showType = STATIC_SHOW_TYPE
        elif (self.path == '/Effects') :
            self.showType = EFFECTS_SHOW_TYPE
        else :
            self.showType = PLAYLIST_SHOW_TYPE
        return doQueryResultsPage()

    def doControlTypePage(self):
        if (self.path == '/Select') :
            self.ctrlType = SELECT_CTRL_TYPE
        else :
            self.ctrlType = CONTROL_CTRL_TYPE
        return doQueryResultsPage()

    def doQueryResultsPage(self):
        json_data  = '{ \"power\": {}, \"show\": {},'
        json_data += '\"show_type\": {}, \"control_type\": {} }'
        json_data = format(json_data, bLightsOn, bLightShowOn, showType, ctrlType);
        self.write(json_data)

def main():
    try:
        server = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyHandler)
        print ('started httpserver...')
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ('^C received, shutting down server')
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The point of the test is to receive a valid request; change a value and return a json string back reflecting the internal state of the server.

However, as soon as I try to load any of the pages, I get the following error message:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50149)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

So my question is, **what am I doing wrong?**

I've taken the code format from the following [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663032/calling-python-dictionary-of-function-from-class) which appears to be trying to do the same things, maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: It looks like the socker server sends 4 arguments to its handler, but the default one (that you've overridden), takes zero (well, just `self`) arguments. You'll want to adjust `__init__` of the handler to take more arguments.

Comment: There are more examples in, for example, the [Python documentation itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example).

Comment: In fact, if you actually look up the documentation for [`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler), you'll immediately see that it takes 3 to 4 arguments.

Comment: I don't understand why you link to the other StackOverflow question: it doesn't appear to do anything like you try to do. Did you make a typo in the link?